# Laravel additional auth information

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Okay, to start easy i have a table called ranks with rows(permissions) those are an int and can be 1 or 0.
The user table has a row with the rank id.

Example users table:
Name: SynteX Email: *@**.nl Rank: 2

Example ranks table:
id:2 permToEdit: 1

I can show the rank id with: Auth::user()->rank But this doesn't help me.
I want to acces the rows of rank like this: Auth::user()->rank->permToEdit. Which is possible if you run the following query:

```
Auth::user()->rank = DB::table('ranks')->select('color')->where([['id', '=', Auth::user()->rank],])->first();
```

That makes it possible but i have to acces it from every controller and every view. So where do i put this line to make it acceable everywhere?

Comment: Read about [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Can a user have 1 or multiple `ranks`?

Answer (score 0):

For relationships you can just add this method to your User model

```
public function rank()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Rank::class);
}
```

But for user's roles/permissions I recommend [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) helper.

Comment: For this to work the column rank must be 'rank_id' or you have to add the column name as a parameter to the relationship method.

Comment: @tam My example will works if `users` table have `rank_id` field.

Comment: That is what I just said.

Comment: @tam Yeah, but what is your problem? With this relationship you can access `rank` object where you want if you have `User` object. Like `$user->rank->any_rank_variable` without any additional queryes

Comment: No problems. From OP's question it seemed like his column was named 'rank', just wanted to give the heads up.

Comment: @tam Yeap, you are right. I missed this. So `return $this->hasOne(Rank::class, 'id', 'rank')` will be correct.

Comment: This wont work, as the column and relationship are called the same. Just rename the column to 'rank_id'

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if I understand you question correctly. But is seems to me that you need a pivot table.

You have a table: 'users'

And a table: 'ranks'

So if you create a pivot table rank_user (Laravel works in an alphabetical order here, so rank comes first, you can change this in you ‘user’ an ‘rank’ Model).

So first you’l need to create the pivot table:

```
Schema::create(‘rank_user', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('rank_id');
            $table->boolean('permToEdit') // withs converts to a ‘tiny int’ in the database
});
```

So then in your User model you’ll need to create:

```
public function ranks() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(‘App\Rank’)->withPivot(‘permToEdit’);
    }
```

And in you Rank model:

```
public function users() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\User')
            ->withPivot('permToEdit ');
    }
```

Now in your User model you could work with the following function

```
public function getPermToEdit()
{
    Return $this->ranks()->wherePivot(‘permToEdit’, true)->first(); 
}
```

Or if you need to pas a specific user id you could:

```
public function getUserPermToEdit($user_id)
{
    Return $this->ranks()->wherePivot('user_id', $user_id)->wherePivot(‘permToEdit’, true)->first(); 
}
```

If all this is new to you check:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships
or
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIBST5vVq84&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEb-tzSN99Zy-39Y1tKl5DB

Comment: Pivot table is not necessary here. But could be a nice suggestion if OP wants to change his approach